# Capture server terminal output in local bash script

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, remote-server, stderr

I'm trying to capture the log output of a piece of software running in server mode on `localhost` in the bash script that triggers the communication with the server via `nc`.

The server is started like this:

`java -Xms4g -Xmx6g -jar target/Semafor-3.0-alpha-04.jar model-dir:../semafor_malt_model_20121129 port:4444`

The communication from the bash script is:

```
cat file | nc localhost 4444 > ./output
```

This captures the `STDERR` output as is the case with `nc` nicely.

But I can see lots of log messages scrolling through in the terminal window where I started the server, and my question is how I can capture these messages in the bash script (and thus save them under a specific filename file.log, which would be different for each file sent)?

I've tried various suggestions, like capturing the output from the bash command in a variable

```
var=$(cat file | nc localhost 4444 > ./output)
```

or even trying to capture the terminal output with `script` but without any success.  I'm clearly out of my depth here, and any pointers would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/):

```
screen -S session_name -L -X eval 'java...'
```

`-L` flag will generate a log with all the stuff you require on the current directory.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Screen is new to me and I seem to be running into errors about java and path components not being found.  Will have a proper go at it tonight, and may have more relevant questions then.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to get this to work. All classpath and other path information seems to get lost when using screen, is there a way around this?  I've tried replacing relative with absolute paths, but some are defined in ENV variables that I cannot change easily. Any ideas?

Comment: There are several ways to get that problem solved, but the easiest way is to use setenv command, you may find more information [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157202/how-to-set-screen-environment-variable-from-bash).